# at the moment of making a return it re-lists the data with the added data and the previous data

Tags: angular

Hello I am trying to update instantly when entering a card without having to reload the page, when doing the return it returns the data and the list of cards appears before updating and the card list with the added data

getstd() {

```
this.API.getListas(this.id, this.idx)
  .subscribe((data: customer[]) => {
    this.customersx = data;
 
    data.forEach((element, i) => {
      this.API.getCards(element.id)

        .subscribe((data2: any) => {

          data2.forEach((elementcard) => { 
            this.customersy.push(elementcard)
          });



        });
    });


  });
```

}

createCard(list: ScrumboardList, close: () => void, id) {

```
var customer = this.formcard.value;
customer.listId = id;

this.API.createCard(customer).subscribe((response) => {
  

  return this.getstd();
});
```

Comment: Please provide more descriptive information. For example what is this.getstd() doing? Include code samples if possible.

Comment: hello @BrianSmithsorry I already added the missing data
could you help me please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are getting the full list back after the api call then on createCard function, you can empty the customers variables since you are setting them again in the getstd() function.

```
createCard(list: ScrumboardList, close: () => void, id) {
  var customer = this.formcard.value;
  customer.listId = id;

  this.API.createCard(customer).subscribe((response) => {

    this.customersx = [];
    this.customersy = [];
  

    return this.getstd();
});
```

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH IT WORKS WITHOUT PROBLEMS ALTO CAPO BROTHER

Comment: Great, glad to help. Be sure to mark this as answer and upvote.